# Google+ API for iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, google-plus, social-networking

After fiddling for a little while with the Google+ API for iOS. I am starting to find my way.
I have code like the following, and it works:

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
[shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Hello Google+ in my iOS app."];
[shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.net/MyContents/"]];
```

Now, it seems that I can't add another line like the last in order to share a second URL. And I can't pass HTML contents to the setPrefillText method. In other words I am somewhat limited.
What do I need to do if I want to make a post with more than one URL?

I can still add several URL full-text, but it is not so nice.
I would like to associate a URL with a text I choose, like in HTML.

Thanks in advance for any indication.